# Is this sort of "infinite ascent" a valid proof that $a + b \le 1 + ab$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, proof-verification, alternative-proof

Today I had to prove that for $a,b \in [0,1]$, we have

$$a + b \le 1 + ab$$

The first proof I found feels rather weird (as in, there should be a much simpler process) and I am not entirely sure that it's correct. Anyhow, I thought:I can square both sides and see that the inequality is true *if and only if*

$$a^2 + b^2  \le 1 + a^2b^2 $$

But this is in the same form as the previous inequality (setting $a_1 = a^2$ and $b_1 = b^2$). I can iterate this process and prove that the original inequality is equivalent to

$$a^n + b^n \le 1 + a^nb^n$$for every $n = 2^k, k \in \mathbb N$ . Now eventually I will find an $n$ such that $a^n, b^n, a^nb^n$ are all small enough such that the inequality holds, hence the first inequality holds, too, and we proved

$$a + b \le 1 + ab$$

Is this logically sound? (And what is a more immediate proof of this)

Comment: The square of a sum is in most cases not the sum of the summands' squares ...

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I'm fully aware of that, but the $2ab$ part cancels out

Comment: Yes, I see. A bit dull of me.

Comment: @Ant I remember seeing a proof of AM-GM inequality by *backward induction*. That is, one  proves it for infinitely many $n$, and then show that,  if true for a specific $n$ then it must be  true for $n-1$.  The infinitely many n$ for this case was all powers of 2 as you have done here. Not sure how it ties up with this.

Comment: The inequality is equivalent to $a(1-b)\leq1-b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your logic is sound. This is because given any $a,b \in [0,1]$ you can find an 'if and only if' argument with a finite number of steps.

Note that the right hand side of the inequality you're proving is greater than $1$, hence it suffices to find $k$ such that $a^n + b^n <1$ where $n = 2^k$. Once you've done this you can use your 'iff'/infinite ascent argument  $k$ times to conclude that the inequality holds for those specific $a$ and $b$. As this holds for any pair $a,b \in [0,1]$ you're done.

Hope this helps. I like this, it's an interesting way of proving this inequality!

Answer (score 2):

The most immediate proof is

$$a+b \leq 1+ab \Longleftrightarrow (1-a)(1-b) \geq 0$$ which is obvious.

And in general,

$$a^n+b^n \leq 1+a^nb^n \Longleftrightarrow (1-a^n)(1-b^n) \geq 0$$

Comment: Why square at all? If $a,b\in [0,1]$ so does $1-a, 1-b$. The product of latter pair is positive. I.e. $1-a-b+ab \geq 0$ QED

Comment: ahah nice, missed that ;-) Anyhow this was not the main point of the question, could you address that? ;-)

Comment: @PVanchinathan Edited just before your comment. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: @Ant Please check the edits and tell me if they address your concern now.

Comment: Well the equality you're trying to estabilish is stronger than what you need (the implication about being greater than 0), so I don't see why the fact that that inequality is not true implies that "reverse induction" fails :-) Also, what suffice to be proven is that "Inequality for $n = 2^{k+1}$ implies inequality for $n = 2^k$

Answer (score 2):

Assume $a,b < 1$ (otherwise the inequality is obvious). Then there is $n$ with $a^n, b^n \leq \frac{1}{2}$. Take $k$ with $2^k \geq n$. Now we have
$$a^{2^k} + b^{2^k} \leq a^n + b^n \leq \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = 1 \leq 1 + a^{2^k} b^{2^k}.$$
The equivalence you've shown yields the result. So yes, your idea should work.

Comment: For $a \in [0,1)$ we have $a^n \overset{n \to \infty}{\to} 0$, don't we?

Comment: Ok, you are right if you meant that. But how does this prove $a+b \leq 1+ab$.

Comment: Everything's written there. I rely on the equivalence
$$a+b \leq 1 + ab \iff (a+b)^2 \leq (1+ab)^2 \iff a^2 + 2ab + b^2 \leq 1 + 2ab + a^2b^2 \iff a^2 + b^2 \leq 1 + a^2b^2.$$

Comment: Sorry for creating the confusion. Anyways, nice answer.